# Model Related Fields - Update and Create using FK

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have two tables. One for Users, one for Equipments.
I managed to make the search for username from other table, but now i want to create an equipment or to update an equipment directly to username, not by user_for_id. Is there any posibilty to do that ? Which would be the steps ? Thank you very much for any guidance.

First table : user_id - primary key, username, password ;

Second table: user_equip_id - primary key, phone_model, phone_model_series, phone_date_acq, nb_sg_model, nb_sg,_date_acq, display_model, display_series, display_date_acq, user_for_id - foreign key to user_id from table1

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Equipment;
use app\models\EquipmentSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

/**
 * EquipmentController implements the CRUD actions for Equipment model.
 */
class EquipmentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],      
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Equipment models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new EquipmentSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Equipment model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Equipment model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Equipment();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->user_equip_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Equipment model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->user_equip_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Equipment model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Equipment model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Equipment the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Equipment::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Model :

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "equipment".
 *
 * @property int $user_equip_id
 * @property string|null $phone_model
 * @property string $phone_series
 * @property string $phone_date_acq
 * @property string $nb_sg_model
 * @property string $nb_sg_series
 * @property string $nb_sg_date_acq
 * @property string $display_model
 * @property string $display_series
 * @property string $display_date_acq
 * @property int $user_for_id
 *
 * @property User $userFor
 */
class Equipment extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'equipment';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['phone_series', 'phone_date_acq', 'nb_sg_model', 'nb_sg_series', 'nb_sg_date_acq', 'display_model', 'display_series', 'display_date_acq', 'user_for_id'], 'required'],
            [['phone_date_acq', 'nb_sg_date_acq', 'display_date_acq'], 'safe'],
            [['user_for_id'], 'integer'],
            [['userFor'], 'safe'],
            [['phone_model', 'phone_series', 'nb_sg_model', 'nb_sg_series', 'display_model', 'display_series'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['user_for_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_for_id' => 'user_id']],
            [['userFor'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            //[['username'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['username' => 'username']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'user_equip_id' => 'User Equip ID',
            'phone_model' => 'Phone Model',
            'phone_series' => 'Phone Series',
            'phone_date_acq' => 'Phone Date',
            'nb_sg_model' => 'NB/GS Model',
            'nb_sg_series' => 'NB/GS Series',
            'nb_sg_date_acq' => 'NB/GS Date',
            'display_model' => 'Display Model',
            'display_series' => 'Display Series',
            'display_date_acq' => 'Display Date',
            'user_for_id' => 'User For ID',
            'userFor.username' => 'Username',

        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[UserFor]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUserFor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_for_id']);
    }
    
    //public function getUsername()
    //{
     //   print_r($equipment->userFor->username);die;
   // }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return EquipmentQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new EquipmentQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

Model Search:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Equipment;

/**
 * EquipmentSearch represents the model behind the search form of `app\models\Equipment`.
 */
class EquipmentSearch extends Equipment
{
    public $userFor;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_equip_id', 'user_for_id'], 'integer'],
            [['phone_model', 'phone_series', 'phone_date_acq', 'nb_sg_model', 'nb_sg_series', 'nb_sg_date_acq', 'display_model', 'display_series', 'display_date_acq'], 'safe'],
            [['userFor'], 'safe'],
            #[['username'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Equipment::find();
        $query->joinWith(['userFor']);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['username'] = [
        'asc' => ['user.username' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['user.username' => SORT_DESC],
        
        ];

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'user_equip_id' => $this->user_equip_id,
            'phone_date_acq' => $this->phone_date_acq,
            'nb_sg_date_acq' => $this->nb_sg_date_acq,
            'display_date_acq' => $this->display_date_acq,
            'user_for_id' => $this->user_for_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'phone_model', $this->phone_model])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'phone_series', $this->phone_series])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'nb_sg_model', $this->nb_sg_model])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'nb_sg_series', $this->nb_sg_series])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'display_model', $this->display_model])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'display_series', $this->display_series])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.username', $this->userFor]);
        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

**Thank you in advance for any guidance or help.**

Comment: Also, right now if i want to update / create a new equipment i have this error : Invalid Call: Setting read-only property: app\models\Equipment::userFor. Any help for this too ? Thank you

Comment: `public $userFor` in `EquipmentSearch` model is conflicting with relation name `userFor`. Change`public $userFor` to something else.

Comment: You can do it. But the foreing key in one table should point to the primary key in the other.